# Won't echo a rounded number

Tags: php

For some reason my code only works when lastpage is equal to 3.
If its equal to 2 it will give an image like this
http://gyazo.com/7a590068ec0e4a6ba4da586c60f36658

if it is = 3 it will give the correct way like this
http://gyazo.com/7188af3281d0964e085b86d8449e80c6

This is the code!

```
<?php
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM html where id='$userid'");
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
$lastpage=$row3['lastpage'];
}
$htmltotal = 12;
$res = floor(($lastpage / $htmltotal) * 100);
?>
```

Now if lastpage is equal to 2 it should give 17 because 16.6777776777 is rounded up to 17. Instead it doesn't show anything. But if it doesn't have to be rounded like 3 which equals to exactly 25 than it does show. Any ideas?

Javascript:

```
$('.about-menu').on('click',function(){

    // progress bar animation
    $('.progress .bar').each(function () {
      var me = $(this),
          datascore = me.attr('data-score'),
          score = $(this).find('.title-score');


          me.animate({
              width: datascore + '%',
              easing: 'swing'
          }, 100),  
          $(score).animateNumbers(datascore, true, 1500);
    });
```

For some reason any number that isn't a multiple of 5 it won't load.

Comment: You are overwriting `lastpage` with the result from a query fetching multiple rows without an `ORDER BY` clause? What I'm saying is: examine what `$lastpage` _is_ at that point, cause you can clearly see `echo floor((2/12) * 100);` works...

Comment: I'm not overwriting lastpage. Im making lastpage equal to a row from the query called lastpage that is matched with the id of the userid. There is no place where I overwrite lastpage at all.

Comment: Also no, it doesn't work even if I do 2/12 rather than $lastpage/$htmltotal. So it has nothing to do with the variables. Plus when it rounds the number it outputs 16, not 17.

Comment: (1) it outputs `16`, not _"nothing"_, so if that fails for you entirely, your problem is further on in the code (2) You're `floor`-ing (rounding down), if you want normal rounding, use.... `round()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) instead of [floor()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) ,your requirement is ceil() and you are using floor()
ceil :-> Returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value if necessary.

```
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM html where id='$userid'");
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
$lastpage=$row3['lastpage'];
}
$htmltotal = 12;
$res = ceil(($lastpage / $htmltotal) * 100);
```

[round()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) work as both ceil and floor function

Comment: Thankyou! Although now it does output the correct number (17) it still won't load 17 like its supposed to.

http://gyazo.com/48a1fce4f1229d401ceac78f65d0847e

See where it says Courses17, I echo'd $res after Courses to test that it does output a number and it does.

Comment: @KevinHarrison i don't know the reason and i know only the problem in the question you posted...

Comment: Well that was the problem in my question D: 

I will post the JS for the progress bar and can someone check if theres something wrong with that? If its any number that isn't 80, 85, 90, etc.. it won't load it. So for example 14, 19, etc.. won't work.

Comment: Rajeev you did give me the correct answer so I will accept it. Thankyou!

Comment: @KevinHarrison - you say it doesn't return correct value. If you do a simple echo in the php-file. Doesn't it return anything then?

Comment: Not until after I changed it to ceil().

Although the issue is with JS for some reason now.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947692/progress-bar-only-loads-multiples-of-5